# Drawing a number line in TikZ with text descriptions

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I was wondering how one could construct the following number line using TikZ:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQtaD.jpg

I've tried reading the other questions here, but the main challenge that I am having is: (1) Creating the three dots "..." in the middle of the number line, and (2) Putting the curly brackets in two parts, and (3) Putting text above and below some of the curly lines.

Thank you!

Comment: Don't focus on the `\dots` and try to draw the line and the ticks first, using `foreach` loop.

Comment: For the curly brackets you can for example take a look at the following `TikZ` library: `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}`

Comment: If you post your code in a compilable example, people will be much more prone to help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- In your question you not show sketch of desired image, only not accessible link.
- I hope, that image in the  @Tom answer is sufficient close to what you after.
- I would draw this picture a slightly differently, as I like to have:

[image]

- I try to write as much as possible concise and clear structured MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, 
                decorations.pathreplacing,%
                    calligraphy,% had to be after decorations.pathreplacing
                calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
             > = Straight Barb,
BC/.style args = {#1/#2}{
        decorate,
        decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,
                    pre =moveto, pre  length=1pt,
                    post=moveto, post length=1pt,
                    raise=#1,
                    #2,% for mirroring of brace
                    },
            ultra thick},
                        ]
\draw [ultra thick,->] (-7.5,0) -- (7.5,0);
    \foreach \i [count=\x from -6] in  {-23,-22,-21,-20,-19,\dotsm,1,2,...,6}
\draw[thick] (\x,3mm) -- ++ (0,-6mm) node (n\x) [below] {$\i$};
%
\draw[BC=4mm/]          (-6,0) -- node[above=6mm] {other text} (-2,0); 
\draw[BC=8mm/mirror]    ( 0,0) -- coordinate[below=11mm] (aux)  (5,0);
\draw[<->, semithick, densely dashed, rounded corners] 
    (n-6) -- node[fill=white] {some text} ++ (0,-1.3) -| (aux);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great, learned a lot. Thank you!

Comment: @Tom, you are welcome,!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution.
Is there a way to make the code more concise? Any advice?

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, decorations.pathreplacing,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [line width=5pt,-{Triangle[length=0.5cm,width=0.5cm]}] (-7.5,0) -- (7.5,0);
\foreach \x in {-6,...,-2} {
\draw [line width=2pt] (\x,-0.5) node (bx\x) [font=\Large,xshift=-6pt,below=0.5cm] {\pgfmathparse{\x-17}$\mathbf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}$} -- (\x,0.5) coordinate (tx\x);}
\draw [line width=2pt] (-1,-0.5) node (bx-1)  [font=\bfseries\Large,below=0.75cm] {\dots} -- (-1,0.5) coordinate (tx-1);
\foreach \x in {0,...,6} {
\draw [line width=2pt] (\x,-0.5) node (bx\x) [font=\Large,below=0.5cm] {\pgfmathparse{\x+1}$\mathbf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}$} -- (\x,0.5) coordinate (tx\x);}
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,raise=10pt,amplitude=20pt}] (tx-6) -- (tx-1) node (TB) [midway,above=1.2cm,font=\large] {\textbf{Other Text}};
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,raise=10pt,amplitude=20pt,mirror}] (bx0.south) -- (bx6.south) node (BB) [midway,below=1cm] {};
\draw [{[scale=2]Triangle}-] ($(bx-6)+(6pt,-10pt)$) -- ++(0,-0.7) node (ST) [below=4pt,font=\large] {\textbf{Some Text}};
\draw [shorten <=6pt,shorten >=6pt,-{[scale=2]Triangle}] (ST.south) .. controls +(-80:1.5cm) and +(200:1.5cm) .. (BB.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]